# Disabling Safari Autofill for credit cards

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, safari

I have an Angular.js app as a payment gateway. Because Angular.js has trouble alerting when a browser auto-fills form data, I have autofill disabled.

As of Safari 7.0.1, though, they no longer recognize the `autocomplete="off"` attribute. That has caused the app to become non-responsive when one auto fills their credit card data.

Is there a way to trick Safari into not recognizing the form as a credit card form?

EDIT

It appears Angular now recognizes when a text field has been auto-filled but not select fields. It's the expiration dates that cause the problems.

Comment: Some one please answer this. I am running in to the same issue.

Comment: I also am running into this issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTPS, then Safari automatically fills certain fields. if you change this to be a http page, the fields are not filled in.

It is annoying behaviour and completely against the W3C standards.

As a workaround, you can add a reference to a http element, such as an image tag, but you lose the padlock. Not a suitable workaround really.